# Elevation not working

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, policykit

Complete newbie here.

Muon recently started giving an error upon installing:

```
This operation cannot continue since proper authorization was not provided
```

After that I noticed I cannot restart/shutdown nor change time.

I tried to reinstall `policykit` (it was installed and running), no deal. Tried to kill the process and restart it, received the following error:

```
Adding new listener  PolkitQt1::Agent::Listener(0x2649c10) for 0x2519e20  "Cannot create unix session: No session for pid 3126" 

** (process:3126): CRITICAL **: polkit_agent_listener_register_with_options: assertion 'POLKIT_IS_SUBJECT (subject)' failed "Cannot register authentication agent!" 

(process:3126): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

`pkexec` and `kdesudo` work, only muon, shutdown, update-manager are affected.